# css3 animate pngs with transparency

Tags: css, png, css-animations

I have images that I want to swap in and out (no slide effect). The first cycle, the images appear stacked on top of each other (since they have holes). All subsequent cycles, it works correctly (only one visible at a time).

Html

```
<div class="small xfade">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

css

```
@keyframes xfade {
    0%   { opacity:1; }
    17%  { opacity:1; }
    25%  { opacity:0; }
    92%  { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
.xfade span {
    animation-name: xfade;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 8s;

    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[All visible at once during first loop](http://jsfiddle.net/3KNa9/3/)

[Only one visible during first loop, but flash](http://jsfiddle.net/3KNa9/4/)

Comment: Not getting what you need

Comment: I don't want all of the images visible at the same time—only one. The first loop, all of the images can be seen on top of each other. After the first loop, they behave correctly. I want the behaviour from after the first loop. Basically what is happening in the second link without the flash between transitions.

Comment: So that's what you achieved already in the second demo? sorry if am getting wrong

Comment: @Mr.Alien, yes, except in the second demo, there is a brief "flash" of white between transitions during the first loop. I want one to immediately follow the other without that white flash.

Comment: Aaaa got it, wait, let me try

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3KNa9/5/

Comment: @Mr.Alien the fade effect is not necessary btw. if they just pop in and out (without moving), that's fine too.

Comment: The demo I provided should match your requirements, though it jerks on first 3 switch

Comment: @Mr.Alien, close, but now the "small"s are a split-second delayed behind "big" while they "flash" in (just no white because big is covering body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An usual scene when doing animations is where you have the same animation for several elements, but you want them to be delayed, making a sort of full cycle.

Then you set a animation-duration of say 8 seconds, and if you have 4 elements, you set a delay of 0 for the first, a delay of 2s for the second, and 4s and 6s for the others.

The problem with this is that the second element only starts animating after 2 seconds. In the meantime, it has the initial properties, that can match, or not, *(usually not)* the properties of the animation.

The best way to solve that is to realize that, if the animation-duration is 8s, then setting the delay to 2s is the same than setting it to -6s. *because if you count 8s starting in -6s, you will end at 2s*. But, then the animation is running from the first moment, with the properties that should have.

So, the delays in your case should be 0s, -6s, -4s, -2s. **Just subtract the transition-duration from the transition delay**.

Whenever you set an animation, and discover than *the first animation is wrong, but after that they are ok*, the likely problem (and solution) is this.

If you want to make everything go faster, but everything else being the same, then you have to reduce **both** the animation duration and all the animation delays

Example setting

```
.xfade span {
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

.xfade span:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: -1s;
}

.xfade span:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.xfade span:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/3KNa9/6/)

Also, let's analyze how the tween time is computed. First of all, you are setting the animation for an element that shares the full time with another 3 elements. That means that every element has 1/4 of the time, that is 25%.

This time has to be divided between time of *full* display and time of *tween*. Inthe original example, tween time is 8%. If you want that reduced, let's say that tween time will be 6%. Then, full display time will be 25 - 6 = 19.

That gives us the first part of the keyframes:

```
@keyframes xfade {
    0%   { opacity:1; }
    19%  { opacity:1; }
    25%  { opacity:0; }
```

Now, for the final keyframes, we have to remember that the tween time is 6, and set that at the end. The keyframe mus be at 100 - 6 = 94. Remainig keyframes:

```
    94%  { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Would you also happen to now how to speed up the transition? I tried adjusting the keyframe percentages to be more "extreme", but the animation got totally out of sync. I'm guessing there's some mystical formula that I'm missing.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Added example at twice the speed.

Comment: Oh sorry, i meant the change from image to image (the "tween" time), not the duration each image is displayed.